# Closed-form expression of $\int_0^T(1-a+a e^{-\lambda t})^n dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

How do I evaluate the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^T(1-a+a e^{-\lambda t})^n dt?
\end{equation}
where $a\in (0,1); n = 3,4,5,6,\cdots; \lambda, T \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.
Is there a way to obtain a closed-form solution or express this in term of some well-known special functions?

Comment: Expand with binomial theorem?

Comment: yes, but I'd like a closed form solution.